# Where to find JXSTransform.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to find "jxstransform.js" because I'm practicing React. Where do you think can I find and download that file?

Comment: [It has been deprecated.](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/06/12/deprecating-jstransform-and-react-tools.html) Use `babel` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you just wanna try react you can use the React jsfiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/reactjs/69z2wepo/

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <div>Hello {this.props.name}</div>;
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
    <Hello name="World" />,
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

NOTE: I need to put some code in order to add the "jsfiddle" link

but I think you should take a look at this link as well.

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tooling-integration.html

Answer (score 0):

If you just started to use react, you probably don't need that file anymore. Just download the react starter pack, you'll see a list of example inside the ZIP file which you can play with.

Download the starter pack here https://facebook.github.io/react/downloads/react-0.14.5.zip